# Unresolved external symbol fail in VERY simple application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

The simple code fails:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World!", L"Just another Hello World program!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup   ... Projects\DX11_3\DX11_3\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)  DX11_3

Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   ... Projects\DX11_3\Debug\DX11_3.exe    1   1   DX11_3

What could be wrong? I've downloaded and installed Windows SDK, added det include folder to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program's entry point is where execution starts at. For a console application, this defaults to `main`. For a Windows application with no console, this defaults to `WinMain`.

The linker is searching for `main`, most likely because you created a console application. Go into your project settings and change the subsystem to Windows. You can find this option in Configuration Settings -> Linker -> System

Answer (score 1):

Strictly and formally speaking, your program doesn't contain a function named main, so it isn't valid C++.

To enable non-standard extensions like WinMain, you will have to make sure you are creating a Windows project, or that the compiler options are set to compile a Windows program.

Answer (score 1):

you are compiling your application as a "Console Application", so Visual Studio tries to find an entry point named `main()`. but your code defines a "GUI Application" with an entry point named `WinMain()`.

you should edit your project settings and set the application type to "Console application" in the Linker settings.